# Tablesorter Plugin Causing JS Error

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using this [jQuery table-sorting plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), which works fine when the page needs it. When it doesn't there is a js error; **$("#results").tablesorter is not a function**, which breaks an js after that in the file.

It have tried to overcome this by wrapping it in an **if** call.

```
if ($('body').hasClass('search') && $('#results'.length)) {
  $("#results").tablesorter({
                        headers : {
                            2: {sorter: false},
                            3: {sorter: false}
                        },
                        debug: false, 
                        sortList: [[0, 0]], 
                        widgets: ['zebra']})
}
```

But this fails miserably.

Any and all ideas on how to solve this are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a mistake in your if statement. Should it be:

```
$('#results').length) {
```

---

The `tablesorter is not a function` error is caused because you haven't loaded the plugin. Either load the plugin, remove the `tablesorter` calls or wrap any calls in an if statement. A simple check would be:

```
if(jQuery().tablesorter) {
   //run plugin dependent code
}
```

Comment: I went with your if statement. Thanks